¿Cómo puedo crear un efecto de texto con animación al pasar el cursor sobre él, utilizando CSS?
Estoy trabajando con dos archivos, un HTML y un CSS (en Visual Studio Code),
y estoy buscando agregar un toque interactivo a mi sitio web y me gustaría crear un efecto de texto que cambie de color o tamaño de forma animada cuando el usuario pasa el cursor sobre él. He intentado utilizar las propiedades hover y transition en CSS, pero no he logrado obtener el efecto deseado. ¿Existe alguna manera de lograr este efecto de texto animado con CSS y sin necesidad de JavaScript?
.texto {
    color: #333;
    font-size: 16px;
    transition: color 0.3s ease;
}

.texto:hover {
    color: #ff0000;
}

Este es un ejemplo básico de cómo intenté implementar el efecto de cambio de color al pasar el cursor sobre el texto utilizando CSS. Sin embargo, no logré obtener la animación suave que estoy buscando.

Por lo que veo en tu código todo está correcto. Si ves que el texto cambia de color pero la transisión no es suave prueba a aumentar el tiempo, cambiando de 0.3s a 1s solo para probar.
O tal vez quieras hacer una animación con la propiedad animation (yo aprendí en el canal AlexCGDesign).
Pero si quieres tener dos tiempos de transición distintos, uno para el hover cuando pases el puntero por sobre el texto y otro para cuando lo quites puedes poner la propiedad transition en ambos elementos.
Por ejemplo:
<p class="texto">Ejemplo</p>

.texto {
    color: #333;
    font-size: 16px;
    transition: color 0.3s ease;
}

.texto:hover {
    color: #ff0000;
    transition: color 1s ease;
}

Así se tardará 0.3 segundos en cambiar de color cuando el puntero esté sobre el texto y tardará 1 segundo en volver a su color original.
Tambíen te recomiendo usar transiciones o animaciones en los contenedores del texto (como las etiqueta a y button) y no directamente sobre el texto mismo (span, p, h1, etc) ya que el espacio es muy pequeño y tendrás problemas de accesibilidad, ya que es díficil atinarle (se recomienda que los elementos clickables sean de minimo 44 x 44 pixeles). Pero todo depende de lo que estés creando.
Y último consejo, sobre buenas prácticas, evita ponerle animaciones o transiciones a elementos que no sean links o botones. Recuerda: si no hace nada, no lo animes. El usuario suele confundirse con esas cosas, le dan click y cuando ven que no pasa nada piensan que la web está mal hecha.
